# loop through all worksheets and add sums/formulas at bottom of each

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro that does two things. First, it will split data into multiple sheets (with each sheet based on the value of a specific column). Second, it will loop through all the sheets and add certain sums and formulas to the bottom of each sheet.

I found a very helpful bit of code to split the sheets which I modified slightly and works fine. And I found another bit of code that will cycle through all the sheets in the document. I'm just not sure how to add the necessary sums/formula fields to the end of each sheet.

The code to loop through the sheets is this:

```
  Sub WorksheetLoop2()

     ' Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
     Dim Current As Worksheet

     ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
     For Each Current In Worksheets

        ' Insert your code here.
        ' This line displays the worksheet name in a message box.
        MsgBox Current.Name
     Next

  End Sub
```

So in the "insert your code here" part I need code that:

1. Finds the last row of data on the sheet
2. Go down one or two rows from there
3. In column A add a label that just says "Total Points"
4. In column B make a cell that sums the total of all the values in column H

And I think I can figure out the rest if I get that far.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you search for each bit of your problem separately instead of trying to find the complete solution at once. Below is assortment of solutions I found after searching for each of your problem.

This will find the last row in Column A and go down two rows and put label as Total Points

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).Select
lastRowInColA = Selection.Row
totPointsRow = lastRowInColA + 2
Range("A" & totPointsRow) = "Total Points"
```

Alternatively you can use this tip from Excel Developor

```
Set rLastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
```

Use below peiece of code to add all numbers in a column

```
columnSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(columns("H:H"))
```

To place this sum in Column B of Total Points row, use the same logic I used previously.

```
Range("B" & totalPointsRow) = columnSum
```